# What does the 24 mean in 192.168.1.0/24 in route table?

Tags: networking

What does the 24 mean in 192.168.1.0/24 in route table?
Sorry for my noob question ;(

Comment: This is not strictly a programming question, but the `/24` is the netmask of the IP range; equivalent to mask 255.255.255.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number after the slash indicates how many subnet mask bits to use.

Comment: @Nike Meyer Thanks man!